# solving system of equations with more equations than unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The following equation is given

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
b_1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
& b_2 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} \\
& & & b_{n-1} & a_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \vdots \\v_{n-1} \\v_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_1\\d_2\\ \vdots \\d_{n-1} \\d_n\end{bmatrix}
$$

The $a_i$s and $b_i$s are unknown and two pair of vectors $\{v^{(1)},d^{(1)}\}$ and $\{v^{(2)},d^{(2)}\}$ are given. We need to find $a_i$s and $b_i$s such that the equality holds.

For each row $1, ... , n-1$, we face a system of linear equations with two equations and two unknowns which is easy to solve. But for the last row, we have two equations and one unknown $a_n$, because $b_{n-1}$ is already obtained in row $n-1$.

How can I handle this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a system of $2n$ equations over $2n-1$ variables, so it is over-determined.

As you correctly observed, going top to bottom, you can solve everything uniquely until the last row. There, if both equations will turn out to be multiples of each other, i.e. the implied value of $a_n$ will be the same, your system will have the unique solution.

Otherwise, it will have no solution at all, since $a_n$ cannot be both needed values at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, More precisely, you mean the equation has solution if

\begin{align*}
b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(1)}+a_nv_{n}^{(1)} &= d_{n}^{(1)}\\
b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(2)}+a_nv_{n}^{(2)} &= d_{n}^{(2)}\\
\end{align*}
So must be
$$
\dfrac{d_{n}^{(1)}-b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(1)}}{v_{n}^{(1)}} = \dfrac{d_{n}^{(2)}-b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(2)}}{v_{n}^{(2)}}
$$

The term $
\dfrac{d_{n}^{(1)}-b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(1)}}{v_{n}^{(1)}} = \dfrac{d_{n}^{(2)}-b_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{(2)}}{v_{n}^{(2)}}
$ is the condition of solvability of the problem?

Comment: @Noone exactly, the two implied values for $a_n$ have to coincide, which they do iff $(d_n^{(1)}, v_n^{(1)}, v_{n-1}^{(1)})$ is a non-zero scalar multiple of $(d_n^{(2)}, v_n^{(2)}, v_{n-1}^{(2)})$.

Comment: If we have $4$ equations with two unknowns, then how it would be?

Comment: @Noone in your problem, it is impossible -- $a_1, b_1, a_2$ are $3$ unknowns for $4$ equations, similar to before. Generally, would need a similar condition -- as for all overdetermined systems -- either extra constraints are equivalent (and thus do not add any extra information and can be ignored) or the system will have no solutions.